# 3ds Max with Parallels on a MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, parallels

I am trying to get 3ds Max to run under Parallels on my 15'' MacBook Pro, but it is ultimatly failing.  To get any decent frame rate I have to put all the setting to low, but even then I get weird graphical "gliches" when I play. Controlls are unresponsive and very laggy as well.

I have increased the video memory to 256mb, but that doesn't seem to have helped.  What else should I do to make the game playable?

Mod-edit: I changed TF2 with a "random" 3D modelling software, which solves gaming related issues.

Comment: Sorry but what is TF2?

Comment: TF2 = Team Fortress 2?  sorry, gaming questions are offtopic here.

Comment: If one replaced "tf2" with "graphically intensive application" the question is all-of-a-sudden a lot valider. I feel the "no vidyagames" rule is more about help IN the game, this is about help with an application that happens to be a game - it's not nothign to do with the game itself. It could be TF2, MW2, or SMB2.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to have much luck with running any games under a VM at this point in time (this answer written in Summer 2009) as the required 3d support is just not up to the task - yet.  This is a "gotta have it" feature that many people are clamoring for, so give it about a year (or two) and they'll get it to "acceptable" performance levels.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CrossOver instead, I know a few people that run it that way, but then again they are doing this on Mac Pros.

Comment: I use CrossOver on one of the newer aluminum MacBook (not pro), it works great for tf2.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a 15" MacBook Pro purchased Summer 2008 and it runs smoothly when I quit CPU hoggin' programs using 1024x768 with everything set to the lowest settings.  Not ideal, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried TF2 on my Vista Parallels 5 Install, but I have been playing [Tom Clancy's Raven Shield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Clancy%27s_Rainbow_Six_3:_Raven_Shield) with great success on my 27" iMac.  It runs at full screen 2560x1440 resolution all settings on High.

This is an old game for sure but I figured it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a solution for the immediate, but recently Valve announced that all their Source Engine games were being ported to the Mac and that existing Steam purchases would be transferable to the Mac version.

So VMs and Wine/Crossovers solutions aren't going to be needed soon.